# How to get instance name from connection string?

Tags: c#

I have connection string.

For example:

```
var mainConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\IntegrationTestInstance;Integrated Security=True;";
```

I need some clean way to get instance name **("IntegrationTestInstance")** from connection string. This should work for any connection string.

I can `split string`, than find `Data Source`, and then get `instance` name after `\` character. But I would like to some clean way to do this.

Comment: What type of application you are creating? Windows Form, Asp.Net, etc.. 
Are you using any ORM?

Comment: As far as I can say, you cannot get that part of the **Data Source** with the DbConnectionStringBuilder without resorting to a split call

Comment: It's true that the duplicate answers the question title, but in this question there is more than the title.